# How to install another theme in magento 2.1.7?

Tags: magento-2.1, theme, installation

I have just installed magento 2.1.7 in windows 7 , in xampp 127.0.0.1:8080 domain and by default it has a luma theme on it , i have downloaded a new theme called home interior .zip format and since i am new to magento i have no idea how to install this theme? anyone please help me,

Thank you.

Comment: You have to extract zip file and keep theme folder inside app/design/frontend

Comment: @Rakesh i have done that but its not showing me in admin's theme.

Answer (score 0):

You have to extract zip file and keep theme folder inside **app/design/frontend**

After keep theme inside frontend folder,You have to run command

You have to run command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-conent:deploy
```

Clear cache.

Now You can check theme in adminpanel.

```
Content -> Design -> Theme
```

You can set your theme from,

```
Content -> Design -> Configuration
```

Thanks.

Comment: i have clear cache as per you suggest and refresh my magento's admin but nothing is showing me .

Comment: please tell your theme full path

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya Is possible Magento 2.0.0 theme support for Magento 2.1.7

Answer (score 0):

- after install theme please run both command.

  `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

  `php bin/magento setup:static-conent:deploy`
- and select your theme in admin go to

> content->design->configuration->select theme

Answer (score 0):

Unzip your downloaded theme file and upload it to your Magento 2 root directory.

Then run these commands in store root directory:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Now, just go to CONTENT → Configuration and activate your uploaded theme.